# How to access a js file from another js file in titanium studio android project

Tags: android, model-view-controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am new at titanium studio and working alloy mvc framework. I hv two js file in controller folder. one is index.js(created automatically when the project was created) and home.js. Now I want to open home.js on button event from index.js(like starting a new activity from another activity in eclipse android app). Here is my code:

index.js:

```
function login_Click(e){
    Ti.include('home.js');
    hello();
}       

$.index.open();
```

where login_click(e) is a button onClick event.

And home.js:

```
function hello(){
    //$.home.open();
    alert("Opened");
}
//exports.hello = hello;
```

but whenever i run it and click the button it gives the error

**location:[25,1]alloy/controllers/home.js**

**massage:uncaught reference error:module is not defined**

**source:*module.export=controller;**

Here is my alloy/controllers/home.js:

```
function Controller() {
    require("alloy/controllers/BaseController").apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    arguments[0] ? arguments[0]["__parentSymbol"] : null;
    arguments[0] ? arguments[0]["$model"] : null;
    var $ = this;
    var exports = {};
    $.__views.home = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: "white",
        id: "home"
    });
    $.__views.home && $.addTopLevelView($.__views.home);
    $.__views.label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: "Hell Yeah",
        id: "label"
    });
    $.__views.home.add($.__views.label);
    exports.destroy = function() {};
    _.extend($, $.__views);
    $.home.open();
    _.extend($, exports);
}

var Alloy = require("alloy"), Backbone = Alloy.Backbone, _ = Alloy._;

module.exports = Controller;
```

Plz help me here. I tried require() method. I tried to directly open using $.home.open(); But nothing worked. What do i have to do???? Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Alloy to do this, to open the Home controller view just do this:

```
function login_Click(e){
    var homeController = Alloy.createController('home');
    // If home.xml's container is a Window this will work
    homeController.getView().open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are trying to call the methods of other js file in different file you need to export that function to use it. 
For eg :

> home.js

```
exports.myFunction  = function(){
    alert("I am in");
}
```

> index.js

```
var home = require("home");
home.myFunction();
```

And there you go.